# Copying the structure of temp hive table to new table and adding additional table properties

Tags: hive, partition

I want to copy the structure of full load temp table and add the addition table properties like partitioned by (partition_col), Format='ORC'

Temp table :

```
Create table if not exists tmp.temp_table( id int,
name string,
datestr string )
```

temp table got created.

Final table :

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp.{final_table_name} (
    LIKE tmp.temp_table
)
WITH (
    FORMAT = 'ORC'  
    partitioned by('datestr')
)
```

But I am getting the error as "Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:63 missing EOF at 'WITH' near 'temp_table' (state=42000,code=40000)"

Any solution to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `like` and instead use create table as (CTAS) `select * from mytab where 1=2`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp.{final_table_name} 
    As select * from tmp.temp_table where 1=2
WITH (
    FORMAT = 'ORC'  
    partitioned by('datestr')
)
```

Like will create an empty table with exact same definition. CTAS will use same column sequence, data type/length,  the sql, and your definition to create new empty table because we are using 1=2.